# Remove query strings from static resources - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How do I fix this site speed recommendation with wordpress to remove query strings from static resources.

*Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources:*

```
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?ver=4.5.3
/wp-content/cache/nextend/web/n2-ss-2/n2-ss-2.css?1467994835
/wp-content/cache/nextend/web/n2/n2.js?1467994835
/wp-content/plugins/smar ... edia/dist/smartslider-frontend.min.js?1467908685
/wp-content/plugins/smar ... artslider-simple-type-frontend.min.js?1467908685
/wp-content/plugins/smar ... nd/media/dist/nextend-frontend.min.js?1467908685
/wp-content/plugins/smar ... dia/dist/nextend-webfontloader.min.js?1467908685
/wp-content/themes/wootique-child/style.css?ver=4.5.3
/wp-content/themes/wootique/style.css?ver=4.5.3
/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.5.3
/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.5.3
```

Wordpress seems to add these strings automatically.

Answer (score 5):

this should do the job..
this removes the querystring on the frontend not the admin site.

Update: Add this into your functions.php file. Ensure that its kept within the PHP tags.

```
function rm_query_string( $src ){   
    $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
    return $parts[0];
}

if ( !is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'rm_query_string', 15, 1 );
    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'rm_query_string', 15, 1 );
}
```

Comment: I tried this and installing plugins like "remove-query-strings-from-static-resources" and it works from browser inspector but Pingdoom and GTmetrix continues to show the suggestion "Remove query strings from static resources".

Comment: What if I want to remove query strings from a few resources, but not all?

Answer (score 1):

[This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/) will remove query strings from static resources like CSS & JS files, and will improve your speed scores in services like PageSpeed, YSlow, Pingdoom and GTmetrix.

Resources with a “?” or “&” in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers, and moving the query string and encode the parameters into the URL will increase your WordPress site performance significant.

Comment: Remove Query Strings From Static Resources Plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove Query String
function nerodev_remove_query_string($src) {
    $parts = explode('?ver=', $src);
    return $parts[0];
}
add_filter('script_loader_src', 'nerodev_remove_query_string', 15, 1);
add_filter('style_loader_src', 'nerodev_remove_query_string', 15, 1);
```

I found this [here](http://nerodev.com/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources-wordpress/)